# want to display two variables using document.getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, function

I'd like to create a form field. And then display two variables (already assigned with values) inside it when the page loads itself. I know I can use "`<input id="formField" value="John Smith"/>` but I'd like to use `document.getElementById` to do this. What is wrong with my code?

The form field loads, but it is empty.

I'm very new to JS....

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
<input type="number" id="formField"/>

<script>

var one = "John";
var two = "Smith";

function concat() {
var x = one.value;
var y = two.value;
var z = one + "" + two;
    document.getElementById("formField").innerHTML = z; 
                                                   //Why doesn't this work?

}

concat();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var one and var two are variables so they do not have a value attribute. Only input elements have a value attribute.

Comment: Oh ok.... do all kinds of input elements have value attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your code

1. `input type = "number"` but you are trying to put a string to its value. Which will not work. So change input type to text
2. `one` & `two` are variables, so there is no `one.value` and `two.value`. Simply `one + two` will work
3. You have to use `.value` instead of  `innerHTML` to put the value back in input

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="formFieldText" value=""/>
```

**JS**

```
var one = "John";
    var two = "Smith";

    function concat() {

    var x = one;
    var y = two;
    var z = one + " " + two;
    console.log(z)
        document.getElementById("formFieldText").value = z; 
    }

    concat();
```

[Click here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hL4xdb5c/)

Comment: Heyyy it worked!!!

Thanks so much!! :) :)  was struggling for hours with that thing!!

Comment: Sure... how do i do that?

oh figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

`input` elements do not have an `innerHTML` property. You want to set the `value` property, like so:

`document.getElementById("formField").value = z;`

Other things to note:

- You're setting `x` equal to `one` and `y` equal to `two`, then just using `one` and `two` directly. No point in having `x` and `y`.
- `one` and `two` don't really have a `value` property - they're just strings.
- Don't forget a space between those strings. It seems like what you want is `one + " " + two` (note the space between the quotes) otherwise your ouput will be `JohnSmith`

Comment: Yes, I got rid of x=one, y=two.... got your point! Thanks! 

So, what if one and two were numbers, would they have a value property then?

Comment: No. As it stands, `one` and `two` are strings, and that's it. So they have any properties or methods that String.prototype has, like `length` and `indexOf()`. But you don't need to reference a `value` property to get the string itself. If you want the value of a primitive value like a number or string, just use the variable name. i.e. `console.log(one)`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/buroxaciba/edit?html,output
innerHTML is normally used for div, span, p and similar elements.
input type number -> text